C# code that returns HTML is giving bad result
I am trying to append html to C# as below
 case enumEmailNotifiationType.TaskGroupOverDueReminder:
     heading = "A pending task is due";
     content.Append("<b>A pending task is due.</b> <br/><br/>");
     content.Append($"Please review and complete pending task. Sign in to <a style='color:#336699' href='{this.ApplicationBaseUrl}'>DC.XXXXX.com</a> for details.<br/><br/>");
     content.Append($"The task is regarding {data.EntityName} <br/><br/>");
     content.Append($"For any questions, please contact <a style='color:#336699' href='mailto:{AreaEmailsCSV(data)}'>{AreaEmailsCSV(data)}</a>.<br/><br/>");
     break;

And
 private string AreaEmailsCSV(EntityDataEmailInfo data)
 {
     string mailTo;
     if (data.AreasReplyTo != null && data.AreasReplyTo.Count != 0)
     {
         var emailLinks = data.AreasReplyTo.ConvertAll(a =>
             $@"<a style='color:#336699' href='mailto:{a.AreaContactEmail}'>{a.AreaContactEmail}</a>");
         mailTo = string.Join(" or ", emailLinks);
     }
     else
     {
         mailTo = "<a style='color:#336699' href='mailto:investmentcompliance@xxxx.com'>InvestmentCompliance@xxxx.com</a>";
     }
     return mailTo;
 }

But I am getting the results as in the pic, I don't' want it to be displayed twice, I want Email displayed only once, where am I doing mistake? Another issue is I can't change the format of AreaEmailsCSV method easily, as it is being used by other methods in other places, need some help, please, thanks in advance.


Typo?  Closely examine the resulting string in your debugger.  You're trying to put an <a> tag inside the href of an <a> tag, and then put another <a> tag within that <a> tag, which is clearly wrong.  If you can't change what AreaEmailsCSV returns then remove the <a> from the consuming code that uses it.

Yes I did, it worked thank you so much @David
